# When does App Store promotional code become effective?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, wiki, appstore-approval

I just submitted my app to the App Store and it's in the reviewing process ([3 Degrees of Wikipedia](http://www.threewiki.com)). I have set the "Availability Date" to a future time as some blogs want to cover my app, and I want the release of the actual app come out at the same time as the reviews.

My Problem is: will the promotional code work for the blog reviewers, because the app is not actually in the public App Store? In other words, can the reviewers try out my app during this past-approval-yet-not-public stage of the app.

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no**, you can't.

In order to redeem a promotional code the app needs to be available to download under iTunes.

If you want to give blog reviewers a chance to look at your app before it's released. Send them a Ad Hoc version of your app. This is the recommend way in sharing your app with a limited circle of reviewers/testers.

You can find out more information on Ad Hoc under the Apple [iOS Developer section](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)